# Get an Array of String from a html Text area without empty lines

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I have a text area in which the user inserts titles of research papers. Each title is placed in a separate line. After submitting the contents of this text area, I have to construct a String array of titles and removing any empty lines from being added to this String array.

This is the html side:

```
 <div class="editor-field">
<textarea class="text-box multi-line" data-val="true" data-val-length="1000 Characters maximum"
          data-val-length-max="1000" id="queryTitles" name="queryTitles" cols="100" rows="10" ng-  model="$parent.queryTitles"></textarea>
```

Submit Search Query

This is JavaScript side:

```
var arrayOfLines = $('#queryTitles').val().split('\n');
```

So far this JavaScript creates String array but it does not remove empty lines if the user adds extra empty lines in the text area.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
var arrayOfLines = $('#queryTitles').val().split('\n').filter(Boolean);
```

[Filter documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method to filter out certain elements

```
var filteredArray = arrayOfLines.filter(function(str){
   return str.length>0;
});
```

Use the polyfill on the linked MDN page if needing to support older browsers